# How can i find a ng-pristine type element with protractor?

Tags: protractor

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xch5w.png)

How can i find a element which does not have an id or model?

Comment: you can find using name attribute `element(by.name("user_name"))`

Comment: Thank you for your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do that, you can refer to this http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy for more locators.

The element in the picture has a name attribute so this -> http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.name will suffice.

*In desperate times, you can put your fate on the css locator*

The quickest and dirtiest way to get the element locator is to right-click the element from the DOM tree (ctrl+shift+i in chrome and the elements tab) and copy the selector

Of course, that's a very dirty way of getting the selector and minor changes to thhe DOM could render your test useless.

Here's a more "refined" way to reference the selectors-> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

To use:

```
element(by.css('selectorHere'))
$('selectorHere') //this is similar to the one above, but shorter
//http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed feedback :)